# A peculiar problem with CPIs

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi

So I'm working on a DAO program and I ran into this really weird error. My program is bespoke, so I'm going to demonstrate the problem with an easier-to-understand program: [coral-xyz/multisig](https://github.com/coral-xyz/multisig). The test suite submits a transaction that recursively calls the multisig program to change the owners, and then asserts that the owners are actually changed.

The really weird error arises when you make a seemingly harmless modification. This is the execute transaction instruction context:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ExecuteTransaction<'info> {
    #[account(constraint = multisig.owner_set_seqno == transaction.owner_set_seqno)]
    multisig: Box<Account<'info, Multisig>>,
    /// CHECK: multisig_signer is a PDA program signer. Data is never read or written to
    #[account(
        seeds = [multisig.key().as_ref()],
        bump = multisig.nonce,
    )]
    multisig_signer: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut, has_one = multisig)]
    transaction: Box<Account<'info, Transaction>>,
}
```

If you simply add `mut` to the list of constraints on `multisig`, transaction execution no longer works. No error is thrown by the program, but the owners are no longer changed. Why!?!? Of course, you don't need the `mut` constraint in this case, but I happen to need it for my program.

The only thing I can think of is that this has something to do with account indexing. When the test suite calls into `execute_transaction`, there are two multisig accounts passed into the instruction (one for `ExecuteInstruction`, one inside ctx.remaining_accounts to pass into `solana_program::program::invoke`). Before, one was non-mut and one was mut, so maybe they existed as separate accounts at the transaction level? And when both are mut, it combines them somehow, which screws things up?

Whatever the case, this is a serious footgun.

Comment: When you say no error is thrown by the program, but the owners don't change, what does that mean? The program runs without error but doesn't work? If an account is not mut and you pass it as mut it makes no difference, unless you generated accountMeta like `const accMetas: AccountMeta = { pubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false};` and forget to set isWriteable to true.

Comment: This should be an issue on anchor github repo, possibly the solana repo itself though not sure.